# GNU GRUB Terminal while dual-booting ubuntu with windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, gnu

I am a windows 10 user and would like to install ubuntu to ascend to the world of Linux. I would like to dual-boot ubuntu with windows 10. But while trying to install boot from usb stick, it always shows me GNU GRUB command-line-ish window. Please let me be clear that I would like to dual-boot. the problem persists with kali too.I would be grateful if anyone would help me or point me to an answer.

Comment: See if this helps https://unix.stackexchange.com)/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot/556752#556752

Answer (score 0):

If what you are referring to is a screen that looks similar to this:

[ubuntu grub screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYiJ4.png)

the option you should select is - "Install Ubuntu" (or very similar)

If it is not Please take a picture and update the question.

Comment: No, it is not like that. It looks more like a command interface where you have to punch a bunch of code to do a thing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nocj4.jpg It looks something like this

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time
does this help ?